# What could be a good configuration for a testing machine?

Tags: virtualization, configuration, ramdisk, automated-testing

In [Zentyal](http://www.zentyal.org) we use virtualization ([ANSTE](http://public.warp.es/anste)) to perform automatic tests that require scenarios with several machines interacting in one or several networks. Currently we have a multicore Xeon machine with 16GB of RAM that we use to create ramdisks where the virtual machines are installed. The use of ramdisk greatly increases the execution speed.

We are thinking in replace this machine with another one that can support more scenarios being deployed at the same time. So our main target is to have a lot of fast RAM and enough processor power to run all the machines (processor hasn't been a problem till now but the more cores the better, of course).

Any recommendation of machines that can support this kind of configuration?

Do you know another efficient way to run this kind of scenarios using virtualization?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The single best piece of advice that I can give is to make your test match your production.  Every time that you buy a new production server, try to buy a matching one for testing.

As they say "practice like you're going to perform."

Comment: +1, i agree. Having a ballsy VM server will allow you to match your potential production server as close as you can. Nowadays, 32GB of ram and dual quad core CPUs will get you close to just about anything you need.